# Delete snapshots except those with specific description

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to delete old AWS snapshots but I need to exclude any with a description value that starts with "Created by CreateImage".

I've tried variations of boto3.resource and boto3.client.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
snapshots = client.snapshots.filter(Description!='Created by CreateImage')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for snapshot in snapshots:
        start_time = snapshot.start_time
        delete_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=790)
        if delete_time > start_time:
            snapshot.delete()
            print('Snapshot with Id = {} is deleted '.format(snapshot.snapshot_id))
```

Right now I have about 10 snapshots older than 790 days, 5 with a description that starts with "Created by CreateImage" and 5 that don't. In testing this out I want to delete those snapshots without that description.

the error I get is:

module initialization error: 'EC2' object has no attribute 'snapshots'

Comment: Use the EC2 client describe_snapshots() method. And do your own filtering of the results - you can't filter on 'value != X' using boto3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `describe_snapshots` and properly pass in filters.

Also, the results are going to be a dictionary, not references to the Snapshot class so you need to update the way you pull out the attributes and delete the snapshot.

Something like:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
snapshots = client.describe_snapshots(Filters=[
        {
            'Name': 'description',
            'Values': [
                'Created by CreateImage',
            ]
        },
    ])['Snapshots']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for snapshot in snapshots:
        start_time = snapshot['StartTime']
        delete_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=790)
        if delete_time > start_time:
            client.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snapshot['SnapshotId'])
            print('Snapshot with Id = {} is deleted '.format(snapshot['SnapshotId']))
```

Reference:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this was helpful but in the end I used John Rotenstein's solution. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that works.

Note the use of `OwnerIds=['self']` which limits results to only snapshots created by your AWS account. Without this, it will return all publicly-available snapshots created by any AWS account.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    delete_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=790)

    ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
    snapshots = ec2_resource.snapshots.filter(OwnerIds=['self'])

    for snapshot in snapshots:
        if not snapshot.description.startswith('Created by CreateImage') and delete_time > snapshot.start_time:
            snapshot.delete()
            print('Snapshot with Id = {} is deleted '.format(snapshot.snapshot_id))
```

Comment: One small edit, I wanted to delete all snapshots that do not have 'Created by CreateImage' in the description. I edited line 13 to read: 'if not snapshot.description.startswith('Created by CreateImage') and delete_time > snapshot.start_time:"

Comment: @John what is difference between `snapshot.delete()` and `client.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=id)` for boto3 and python3

Comment: Ah! This is `resource` vs `client`. Basically, `client` methods map exactly the AWS API calls. The `resource` methods are a more Pythonic way of traversing data rather than having to parse JSON. Sometimes things are easier with the `resource` methods, but it's really a personal preference.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Both are work same ? , If I not pass any snapshotId in `snapshot.delete()` then it will delete current id snapshot ? Here I added code for delete, Is It work fine ?  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295917/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-tags-in-boto3/63370241#63370241

Comment: You don't really "pass" a SnapshotId to `snapshot.delete()`. Rather, you obtain the snapshot as an object in the `snapshot` variable, then call `.delete()` on it.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful information, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63295917/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-tags-in-boto3/63370241#63370241 Here I wanna to know that given link answer will work for deleting snapshot ? If anything is not correct, Please modify the answer.