# attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'tags' in boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

Here I want to filter snapshots by the tags in python3 as below :

```
res = c.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['012345678900'],Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Value': ['nonprod*']}])

for s in res:
    If 'nonprod' in s.tags :
       if s.tags == 'nonprod':
          s.delete()
          print ("snapshotlist1: %s" % s.id)
    elif 'prod' in c.tags
        if s.tags == 'prod':
          print ("snapshotlist2: %s" % s.id)
```

getting error in python3 is "attributeerror 'str' object has no attribute 'tags'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[describe_snapshots](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots) returns output in the form of:

```
{
    'Snapshots': [
        {
            # others not shown
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    'NextToken': 'string'
}
```

Thus you should have in the beginning of the loop:

```
for s in res['Snapshots']:
```

Also you have to iterate over all tags, as `Tags` is a list:

```
for s in res['Snapshots']:
    for tag in s['Tags']:
        if tag['Key'] == 'nonprod':
            print("snapshotlist1: %s" % s['SnapshotId'])
        elif tag['Key'] == 'prod':
            print("snapshotlist2: %s" % s['SnapshotId'])
```

Comment: I added as you mentioned but getting error on the "If" condition, Can you show example for same, plesse

Comment: @Nullpointer Because you have to iterate over tags. You can check updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I able to print tag value but here trying to print snapshotId in the Print section.

Comment: I tried with `s.SnapshotId`, getting `'dict' object has no attribute 'Snapshotid'` on print

Comment: @Nullpointer Ah yes, my mistake. It should be `s['SnapshotId']`.

Comment: what is difference between snapshot.delete() and client.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=id) for boto3 and python3 ? Can I used `s.delete()` as i added below answer ? It will work for delete specific `nonprod` tag snapshot ?

Comment: @Nullpointer Hi. If this is new issue, a new question would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version is also works :

Added `Value()` method which compare values in dictionary  :

```
for s in res['Snapshots']:
    for tag in s['Tags']:
        if 'nonprod' in tag.value():
            s.delete()
            print("snapshotlist1[Deleted]: %s" % s['SnapshotId'])

        elif 'prod': in tag.values():
            print("snapshotlist2: %s" % s['SnapshotId'])
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please clarify why did you un-accepted my answer?  Because it seems that you took my answer, change it incorrectly, (`tag.value:():`  is wrong and is not a valid python syntax), and accepted it as your own?